# Why does DC current pass initially through a capacitor while it is charging?

Tags: capacitor

I have this DC circuit:
[image: My DC Circuit]

Here, I am viewing the scope of the resistor (and as usual, green is voltage, and yellow is current). To my understanding, a capacitor is made by putting a layer of insulator between two metal plates. The plates store charges and the insulator prohibits the charges to pass through. But, here I can see that while the capacitor is charging, there is a voltage and a current passing across the resistor. If the capacitor had a layer of insulator in between the two metallic plates, then according to my understanding, it should not have allowed even a small amount of current to pass through because the insulative layer should have blocked the current. But as I can see, this is not the case.

So, my question is, how does a capacitor allow DC current to pass through while it is charging? I have tried to search a lot about it on the internet, but every site mentions that it does, not how it does.

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Ok. But, how does this current pass the insulator layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is true that electrons don't go through the insulator of the capacitor, so there is no '*current flowing*' in the sense of electrons passing from one side to the other.

But, as the charges in one plate of the cap have influence on the charges on the other side (attracting or pushing) there is some kind of '*current*' going through. Maxwell called it '**displacement current**'. And this '*current*' goes through.

When charges start accumulating in one plate of the cap, they push the charges in the other side, at the beggining a lot, like a short circuit, until the cap is charged and it stops.

Actually what goes through is the energy that transport the electromagnetic field produced by the electrons moving. The energy is what goes through.

We tend to think in a electrical circuit like a pipe where electrons move around all the way inside the wire, making all the things in the circuit work.  But this is not correct. The electrons don't need to move around like water in a closed pipe circuit. Electrons when moving produce a electromagnetic wave that is what move around and transport the energy.

In your example, electrons can never complete the circuit because the capacitor is in the middle.

With AC you can ligth a bulb, but electrons just move forward and backward all the time, as voltage sign changes. They 'vibrate' but in average they stay around the same place all the time. So they don't need to go to the bulb to bring the energy there.
You can put a capacitor in series in the middle and the bulb will light anyway.

Answer (score 2):

To store charge into the capacitor, you need to move that charge into it.

Moving charges in a wire is current.

Comment: But how does this charge move while there is an insulator in between? Is it that the +ve charges are moving to one plate of the capacitor from the +ve terminal of the battery (i.e. electrons from one plate of the capacitor are moving to the +ve terminal of the battery), and -ve charges are moving to the other plate of the capacitor from the -ve terminal of the battery, that causes the look as if current is flowing 'through' the capacitor (just like in AC circuit)?

Comment: The current flows to charge the capacitance. A transient DC circuit is an AC circuit until transient has settled and it is a DC circuit. Displacement current could be the term you are looking for. Or you can think the capacitor as a battery, you also must push current into battery to charge it to some voltage.

Answer (score 1):

No conduction current flows through a capacitor except for a tiny leakage current.

What you are seeing is charge flowing onto one plate and off of the other plate giving the illusion that charge (current) is passing through the capacitor between the plates.

As charge flows onto one plate and off of the other plate, the voltage difference between the plates changes.

Having said that, there is a non-conduction current passing between the plates of a capacitor. This current was proposed by Maxwell and is called displacement current. Displacement current is related to electromagnetic radiation.

The magnitude of the displacement current is equal to the magnitude of the conduction current which is flowing along the wires and on to or off of the plates on either side of the capacitor but there is no conduction current flowing through the capacitor except for the tiny leakage current.

Even for an ac current, no conduction current passes through the capacitor. In the case of ac current (charge) is flowing on to and off of the two plates via the wires on either side of the capacitor in a repetitive fashion. However you will often see it mistakenly and confusingly stated that ac current flows "through" a capacitor

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same question before, but after some thinking I came up with an explanation.

Consider a bulb and an uncharged capacitor connected in series with a DC voltage source (a battery, for example). There are three possible phases during the charging of the capacitor in the circuit: **Initial uncharged phase**, **Charging phase**, **Final charged phase**.

1. **Initial uncharged phase**
   During this phase, a DC voltage has just been applied to the circuit. The charge build-up inside the capacitor is (nearly) zero, so it is uncharged. Both the conductors of the capacitor are at 0 volts. **The bulb does not glow.**
2. **Charging phase** (source of main confusion)
   During this phase, the charge build-up inside the capacitor is quite significant, such that it can no longer be avoided. This charge build-up creates a potential difference between the two conductors inside the capacitor. The conductor which is connected to the positive potential of the DC voltage source gets positively charged and gains some positive potential, **however this positive potential is less than the applied voltage**. This positive potential electrostatically induces an equivalent negative potential in the other conductor. However, since the positive potential in the first conductor is less than the applied voltage, **the induced negative potential is also less than the applied voltage** in the second conductor. If, for example, a DC voltage of 5 volts has been provided in the circuit by a battery and the capacitor has only charged up to 2 volts (i.e. the positively charged conductor has +2 volts potential and the negatively charged conductor has -2 volts potential), then **the negatively charged conductor of the capacitor (at -2 volts) is still at a higher potential with respect to the negative terminal of the battery, which is at -5 volts.** Batteries and similar sources of DC voltages maintain constant potential difference (say, *V* volts) between their terminal wherein their positive terminal is always at +*V* volts and their negative terminal is always at -*V* volts. Now since the negatively charged conductor of the capacitor is still at a higher potential with respect to the negative potential of the applied voltage, **a current flows through the bulb and the bulb glows.** This current gets weaker with time, as the capacitor continues to charge from 0 volts upto the applied DC voltage, when the current no longer flows.
3. **Final charged phase**
   This is the phase when the capacitor has (nearly) acquired the full voltage that is applied across the circuit, i.e. the capacitor is fully charged. This means that the positively charged conductor has acquired +5 volts (according to the example cited above) and the negatively charged conductor has acquired -5 volts. Now, **since the applied negative potential is same as that of the capacitor (-5 volts) no current flows through the capacitor when it is fully charged, hence the bulb will no longer glow.**

I hope I was able to explain. Should you have any doubt, feel free to comment below.